# Activerecord Join not returning all expected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, postgresql-9.3

I've got a pre-existing postgres database that I'm attempting to query.  I've set up two models, Customer and Equipment.  I'm trying to query two tables joining them with a non-standard key.  No matter what I've tried, I get back only the result from one table.  I've tried changing the ActiveRecord behavior to use the non-standard key as well as find_by_sql().  I also disabled the default table pluralization because of the existing table structure.  Am I missing something obvious?

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false

    class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.primary_key = :acct
      has_many :equipment, foreign_key: 'acct'
    end

    class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
      self.primary_key = :acct
      belongs_to :customer, foreign_key: 'acct'
    end

    me@nc:~/rails_workspace/pg_test$ rails c
    Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0.rc2)
    2.2.1 :001 > Customer.first()
      Customer Load (16.9ms)  SELECT  "customer".* FROM "customer"  ORDER BY "customer"."acct" ASC LIMIT 1
     => #<Customer acct: "000002", franchise: "501", name: "NAME", address: "STREET ADDR", city: "CITY", state: "ST", zip: "ZIPCODE", phone: "1234567890", email: "email@domain.com", installdate: "2014-02-20", consumptiondate: nil, parent: "", sentoverage: false, exempt: false, pin: "", locked: false, status: "ACT"> 
    2.2.1 :002 > Equipment.first()
      Equipment Load (128.3ms)  SELECT  "equipment".* FROM "equipment"  ORDER BY "equipment"."acct" ASC LIMIT 1
     => #<Equipment mac: "26225070", acct: "000002"> 
    2.2.1 :003 > 


    2.2.1 :009 > Customer.find_by_sql("Select c.*, e.* from customer as c, equipment as e where e.acct = c.acct and c.acct = '000002' limit 1")

    Customer Load (53.9ms)  Select c.*, e.* from customer as c, equipment as e where e.acct = c.acct and c.acct = '000002' limit 1
     => [#<Customer acct: "000002", franchise: "501", name: "NAME", address: "STREET ADDR", city: "CITY", state: "ST", zip: "ZIPCODE", phone: "1234567890", email: "email@domain.com", installdate: "2014-02-20", consumptiondate: nil, parent: "", sentoverage: false, exempt: false, pin: "", locked: false, status: "ACT">] 

    2.2.1 :010 > Customer.joins('FULL OUTER JOIN equipment ON equipment.acct = customer.acct').limit(1)
      Customer Load (119.9ms)  SELECT  "customer".* FROM "customer" FULL OUTER JOIN equipment ON equipment.acct = customer.acct LIMIT 1
     => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Customer acct: "000002", franchise: "501", name: "NAME", address: "STREET ADDR", city: "CITY", state: "ST", zip: "ZIPCODE", phone: "1234567890", email: "email@domain.com", installdate: "2014-02-20", consumptiondate: nil, parent: "", sentoverage: false, exempt: false, pin: "", locked: false, status: "ACT">]> 

    2.2.1 :011 > Customer.joins(:equipment)
    ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'equipment' was not found on Customer; perhaps you misspelled it?
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:218:in `find_reflection'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:223:in `block in build'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:222:in `each'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:222:in `map'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:222:in `build'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:99:in `initialize'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1039:in `new'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:1039:in `build_joins'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:863:in `build_arel'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:855:in `arel'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:638:in `exec_queries'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:514:in `load'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_record/relation.rb:629:in `inspect'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/me/rails_workspace/pg_test/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@pg_test/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.1 :012 >
```

**Edit**

Modified the Equipment class changing the belongs_to :equipments to :equipment.  Resulted in fixing the ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'equipment' error.  But still no fix for the join.  If I manually query the Equipment table using the "key" from the Customer table, the data record is found.

```
2.2.1 :008 > Customer.joins(:equipment).limit(1)
  Customer Load (11.9ms)  SELECT  "customer".* FROM "customer" INNER JOIN "equipment" ON "equipment"."acct" = "customer"."acct" LIMIT 1
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation > [#<Customer acct: "000002", franchise: "501", name: "NAME", address: "STREET ADDR", city: "CITY", state: "ST", zip: "ZIPCODE", phone: "1234567890", email: "email@domain.com", installdate: "2014-02-20", consumptiondate: nil, parent: "", sentoverage: false, exempt: false, pin: "", locked: false, status: "ACT">]

2.2.1 :017 > Equipment.where(acct: '000002')
  Equipment Load (76.5ms)  SELECT "equipment".* FROM "equipment" WHERE "equipment"."acct" = $1  [["acct", "000002"]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Equipment mac: "26225070", acct: "000002">, #<Equipment mac: "23126536", acct: "000002">, #<Equipment mac: "00E06F76A08A", acct: "000002">]>
```

Comment: It may be related to the way you've declared the relations. You should have only one `belongs_to` (the class with the foreign key column). The other class should have an `has_one` or `has_many`. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Typo in my copy/paste.  Updated post

Comment: What's wrong with the join now? The output from `Customer.joins(:equipment).limit(1)` doesn't necessarily look wrong to me. What am I missing? Maybe you're expecting `Customer.joins` to return an `Equipment`, but you would need to do `Equipment.joins(:customer)` to do that.

Comment: Remove `foreign_key: 'acct'` from `has_many :equipment, foreign_key: 'acct'`

Comment: SOLVED.  I thank you both.  SharvyAhmed - This solved my issue as did JasonSwett's response.    Both of your suggestions reduced the database query hits.  Jason's didn't require the modification to the model.  Is there a benefit to one over the other?  I'll have to look at scopes again.  But I don't understand, yet, the reason for the issue to begin with.  The generated SQL should have clearly worked.  In fact, Customer.by_equipment(mac: '26225070') generated the exact same SQL as my original Customer.joins(:equipment).limit(1) with the exception of not passing a filter on the mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simpler solution define a `scope` `by_customer` in `Equipment` model,

```
class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :by_customer,->(customer_conditions) { joins(:customer).where(customer: customer_conditions)}    
end
```

and following `scope` `by_equipment` in `Customer` model,

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :by_equipment,->(equipment_conditions) { joins(:equipment).where(equipment: equipment_conditions)}
end
```

> To find Equipments of Customer '000002'

```
@equipments = Equipment.by_customer(acct: '000002')
```

> To find Customer who has an equipment of mac address is '26225070'

```
@customer = Customer.by_equipment(mac: '26225070')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might see what you're missing.

`Customer.joins(:anything)` will return a collection of `Customer`.

`Equipment.joins(:anything)` will return a collection of `Equipment`.

Maybe you already understood that but maybe not.

If you want a resultset that's a mix of the two, I think you'd have to come at it from a different angle entirely, and I think I'd need to have a better understanding of what you're ultimately after in order to be able to provide any good advice on that.

**Edit:** to get equipment belonging to a particular customer:

```
Equipment.joins(:customer).where('customer.acct = ?', '000002')
```

To get customers for equipment `mac`:

```
Customer.joins(:equipment).where('equipment.mac = ?', '26225070')
```

Comment: Really looking for something simple.  I want a query returning all equipment belonging to Customer.  Generally would pass a condition filtering a specific key.  Also want to be able to do a reverse query... return customer record that has acct = x from equipment table having mac = x

Comment: Thanks Jason!  Shavvy's answer was a solution too.  His required adding a scope to the models.  I'd like to better understand why my query didn't return a collection as the only thing where doing here is passing a condition filter on mac or acct.